# Problem with showing multiple infowindows for multiple polygon

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm getting a problem with showing multiple infowindow for multiple polygons in google map api. multiple polygons are generated, but when I click one of the polygon, infowindow did not showing.

i've tried some of the solution in stackoverflow and the infowindow still not showing.

and here is my code, hope someone can help.

```
var locations = [
   ['2',
    -7.928363082196162,
    110.29961786496813,
    '#FF0000',
    '<div id="content">'+
    '<div id="siteNotice">'+
    '</div>'+
    '<h4 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">2</h4>'+
    '<h6>Test</h6>'+
    '<div id="bodyContent"><p>'+
    '<ul>'+
    '<li> address1' +
    '<li> name1' +
    '<li> <a href="#" target="_blank">Detail</a>' +
    '</ul></div></div>',
      [
         {lat:-7.928484678360535, lng:110.29984203643903},
         {lat:-7.928317314428722, lng:110.29931728739098},
         {lat:-7.928261526436312, lng:110.2993400861676},
         {lat:-7.928326612426706, lng:110.29984970588043}
      ]
   ],
   ['4',
    -7.929468936295299,
    110.29790183540183,
    '#FFFF00',
    '<div id="content">'+
    '<div id="siteNotice">'+
    '</div>'+
    '<h4 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">4</h4>'+
    '<h6>Test 2</h6>'+
    '<div id="bodyContent"><p>'+
    '<ul>'+
    '<li> address2' +
    '<li> name2' +
    '<li> <a href="#" target="_blank">Detail</a>' +
    '</ul></div></div>',
      [
         {lat:-7.92956324428696, lng:110.29753265447664},
         {lat:-7.929071779867816, lng:110.29795204300183},
         {lat:-7.929048809572604, lng:110.29787905276964},
         {lat:-7.928977631597796, lng:110.29787925026733},
         {lat:-7.928972162828607, lng:110.29773508202754},
         {lat:-7.929113352484229, lng:110.2977215078638},
         {lat:-7.929107592513504, lng:110.29744912881154}]
      ],
];

var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[0][1], locations[0][2]);

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
zoom: 16, //level zoom
scaleControl: true,
center:latLng,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var line_locations, lahanPath, i;
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
   line_locations = locations[i][5];
   lahanPath = new google.maps.Polygon({
       path: line_locations,
       geodesic: true,
       map:map,
       strokeColor: locations[i][3],
       strokeOpacity: 0.5,
       strokeWeight: 0.5,
       fillColor: locations[i][3],
       fillOpacity: 0.35
   });

google.maps.event.addListener(lahanPath, 'click', (function(lahanPath, i) {
return function() {
   infowindow.setContent(locations[i][4]);
   infowindow.open(map, lahanPath);
   }
})(lahanPath, i));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are going to provide a second argument to [InfoWindow.open](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/info-window#InfoWindow.open), it needs to be a "anchor" (the only native anchor in the API is a Marker, so a Polygon doesn't work):

> **open**   open([map, anchor])
>   **Parameters:**
>   map (optional):  Map|StreetViewPanorama
>   anchor (optional):  MVCObject
>   Return Value:  None
>   Opens this InfoWindow on the given map. **Optionally, an InfoWindow can be associated with an anchor. In the core API, the only anchor is the Marker class.** However, an anchor can be any MVCObject that exposes a LatLng position property and optionally a Point anchorPoint property for calculating the pixelOffset (see InfoWindowOptions). The anchorPoint is the offset from the anchor's position to the tip of the InfoWindow.

For it to work without an anchor (i.e. with a Polygon), set the InfoWindow's `position`.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(lahanPath, 'click', (function(lahanPath, i) {
return function() {
   infowindow.setContent(locations[i][4]);
   infowindow.setPosition(latLng);
   infowindow.open(map);
   }
})(lahanPath, i));
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/dohgm8bc/)

[image]

**code snippet:**

```js
var locations = [
   ['2',
    -7.928363082196162,
    110.29961786496813,
    '#FF0000',
    '<div id="content">'+
    '<div id="siteNotice">'+
    '</div>'+
    '<h4 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">2</h4>'+
    '<h6>Test</h6>'+
    '<div id="bodyContent"><p>'+
    '<ul>'+
    '<li> address1' +
    '<li> name1' +
    '<li> <a href="#" target="_blank">Detail</a>' +
    '</ul></div></div>',
      [
         {lat:-7.928484678360535, lng:110.29984203643903},
         {lat:-7.928317314428722, lng:110.29931728739098},
         {lat:-7.928261526436312, lng:110.2993400861676},
         {lat:-7.928326612426706, lng:110.29984970588043}
      ]
   ],
   ['4',
    -7.929468936295299,
    110.29790183540183,
    '#FFFF00',
    '<div id="content">'+
    '<div id="siteNotice">'+
    '</div>'+
    '<h4 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">4</h4>'+
    '<h6>Test 2</h6>'+
    '<div id="bodyContent"><p>'+
    '<ul>'+
    '<li> address2' +
    '<li> name2' +
    '<li> <a href="#" target="_blank">Detail</a>' +
    '</ul></div></div>',
      [
         {lat:-7.92956324428696, lng:110.29753265447664},
         {lat:-7.929071779867816, lng:110.29795204300183},
         {lat:-7.929048809572604, lng:110.29787905276964},
         {lat:-7.928977631597796, lng:110.29787925026733},
         {lat:-7.928972162828607, lng:110.29773508202754},
         {lat:-7.929113352484229, lng:110.2977215078638},
         {lat:-7.929107592513504, lng:110.29744912881154}]
      ],
];

var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[0][1], locations[0][2]);

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
zoom: 16, //level zoom
scaleControl: true,
center:latLng,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var line_locations, lahanPath, i;
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
   line_locations = locations[i][5];
   lahanPath = new google.maps.Polygon({
       path: line_locations,
       geodesic: true,
       map:map,
       strokeColor: locations[i][3],
       strokeOpacity: 0.5,
       strokeWeight: 0.5,
       fillColor: locations[i][3],
       fillOpacity: 0.35
   });
   

google.maps.event.addListener(lahanPath, 'click', (function(lahanPath, i) {
return function() {
   infowindow.setContent(locations[i][4]);
   infowindow.setPosition(latLng);
   infowindow.open(map);
   }
})(lahanPath, i));
}
```

```css
html, body, #map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk">
</script>
```